# Parsing JSON String to JObject is not giving the expected output

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I am trying to parse JSON string into `JObject` using `JObject.Parse()`.

But its not working ,This is my code:

```
string json="{\"hashkey\":\"paphAsethE2rexev6c5qAbayu3ebEc\",\"expiration\":\"2016-11-24T12:00:00.000Z\"}";

JObject resourceJson = JObject.Parse(json);
                        return Ok(resourceJson);
```

but in the output some value of expiration is missing that is(.000)

**Expected Result:**

```
   {
      "hashkey": "paphAsethE2rexev6c5qAbayu3ebEc",
      "expiration": "2016-11-24T12:00:00.000Z"
    }
```

**the result which i am getting is:**

```
{
  "hashkey": "paphAsethE2rexev6c5qAbayu3ebEc",
  "expiration": "2016-11-24T12:00:00Z"
}
```

please help

Comment: are you sure JObject lost milliseconds? Did you try to parse more then 0 ms and check value in DateTime?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the DateTime format in `WebApiConfig.cs`:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    //...

    var converter = new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.IsoDateTimeConverter 
                                     {DateTimeFormat="yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fffK"};
    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(converter);

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Tried this its working  but the problem is if the string has "2016-11-24T12:00:00Z" even then its parsing it a s"2016-11-24T12:00:00.000Z"

Comment: When you call `JObject.Parse()`, it loses the information about the original format, so you can't preserve whether milliseconds were specified or not.